# Why CustomeMembershipProvider is not getting invoked?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

After looking at multiple SO q/a
I did following:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : SimpleMembershipProvider
{

    public override string CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password, IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
     // code to insert data into UserAccounts and UserProfiles tables 
     // using simple sqlconnections
    }
}
```

Database tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE UserAccounts
(
UserNumericId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
LoginName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE UserProfiles
(
UserNumericId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
DisplayName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
PrimaryEmail VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
)
```

Web Config has

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Helpers.CustomMembershipProvider, assembly" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

And in global.asax Lazyinitialzation using

```
public class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ApplicationServices", "UserAccounts", "UserAccountId", "LoginName", autoCreateTables: false);
    }
}
```

Still when I call from my Register controller action the following statement

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { DisplayName= model.DisplayName, PrimaryEmail = model.PrimaryEmail});
```

The breakpoint in my custom provider does not get hit. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Is your CustomMembershpProvider really in the Helpers namespace and your assembly name "assembly" as shown in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

You have overridden the incorrect method in SimpleMmebershipProvider. There are several overloaded methods for CreateUserAndAccount.  If you look at the [source code for WebSecurity](https://github.com/aspnetwebstack/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/WebMatrix.WebData/WebSecurity.cs) you can see it calls the one with this signature [[SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUserAndAccount Method (String, String, Boolean, IDictionary)]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537973%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Here is the code for WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount:

```
    public static string CreateUserAndAccount(string userName, string password, object propertyValues = null, bool requireConfirmationToken = false)
    {
        ExtendedMembershipProvider provider = VerifyProvider();
        Debug.Assert(provider != null); // VerifyProvider checks this

        IDictionary<string, object> values = null;
        if (propertyValues != null)
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary(propertyValues);
        }

        return provider.CreateUserAndAccount(userName, password, requireConfirmationToken, values);
    }
```